# Intershop | dB migrate

Tags: pipeline, gradlew, dbmigrate, intershop, gradle.properties

"Address already in use" This is the error which I get while doing dbmigration, I have written the AddService and Addconfiguration properties file now wanted to do dbmigration and getting this error. How to fix this? Thanks in advance

Tried to check and change the orm property file

Answer (score 2):

Please check and make sure you start `dbmigrate` only when no other Java application server process is running. If you're using windows check the system Services if any `Intershop` related service is (automatically) started.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue. I can start DBprepare/Migrate alongside a running server.